# Trouble in getting content from a webp-page content using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have a problem with getting some content by using jsoup. Actually content is in a form like this:

```
<li>
<p>
    <span class=”title” style =”font-weight:lighter”> Title </span> <br/>
    <span class=”time”>Time Date </span>
</p>

<p class=””> Description
</p>

</li>
```

I am getting the **Title** and **Date-Time** by using this code snippet.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(60*1000).followRedirects(true).get();

        for( Element element : doc.select("#incidents") ) {
            String title = element.select("span.title").text() ;
            String timeDate = element.select("span.time").text() ; 

            //String description =  element.select("p").first().text();

        }
```

Now I want to get the **description** i.e. `<p class=””> Description</p>` but I have no idea about it. I have tried different methods from many links but in vain. Anyone having idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution; I'm using now

`String description = element.select("p[class= ]").text();`

And it gives me the required data/content.